# SMS fetch query not displaying name and date

Tags: java, android, sms

I am trying to display the 4 entries in table layout but it only takes Address and Body and display them but when i enter the other 2(name and date) the program crashes. I think my query is ok . Please help

```
package com.androidhive.loginandregister;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SMS extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sms);
        List<String> aa=getSMS();

    }
    public List<String> getSMS(){
         List<String> sms = new ArrayList<String>();
            Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
            Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, null);
            TableLayout table= (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table1);



            while (cur.moveToNext()) {

                   String address = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));
                   String body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
                   String date = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("date"));
                  String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("name"));
                   TextView address1= new TextView(this);
                   address1.setText(address);
                   TextView body1= new TextView(this);
                   body1.setText(body);
                   TextView date1= new TextView(this);
                   date1.setText(date);
                   TextView name1= new TextView(this);
                   name1.setText(name);

                   TableRow row= new TableRow(this);
                   row.addView(address1);
                   row.addView(body1);
                  row.addView(name1);
                   row.addView(date1);

                   table.addView(row);


                  sms.add("Number: " + address + " .Message: " + body + "Name :" + name + "Date: " + date);  

              }enter code here
            return sms;

        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sm, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we dont have 'name' column in sms table, it will be stored as recipient id.

To solve this problem you need to knw the column name that are present in stock messaging application database.

If u are using Emulator, try accessing the database using adb command.

```
~android-sdk\platform-tools>adb shell
$ cd /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases
cd /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases
$ sqlite3 mmssms.db
sqlite3 mmssms.db
SQLite version 3.6.22
Enter ".help" for instructions
sqlite> .headers on
sqlite> SELECT * FROM threads;
sqlite> SELECT * FROM sms;
```

Now you can see how the data is present, and use correct column name.

If u are trying executing in device, try adding

> String[] colNames = cursor.getColumnNames();

Then iterate for column names, to know whether name and date exists.

Cheers !!